# Find partial duplicates in a table with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to find partial duplicate records in my Trip table below:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td> Port </td><td>TripId</td><td>StatusId</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475210 </td><td>500013</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475211</td><td>500013</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475212</td><td>500013</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475213</td><td>500012</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475214</td><td>500012</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475215</td><td>500045</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475216</td><td>500045</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475217</td><td>500045</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475218</td><td>500045</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td> 475218</td><td>500045</td><td>12</td></tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The last 2 records should not have occurred**(any pair of Port/TripId should not have different status in my table) and i would like to find all similar records in the entire table. The table shown above is just an extract from my trip table that contains several many more records. These are loaded in memory as a custum collection

```
public  class Trip
{
   public string Port {get;set;}
   public string TripId {get;set;}
   public string StatusId {get;set;}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The html table was only meant to format my data to show it as a table.  :-)

Comment: same port same tripId (475218/500045)

Comment: same port AND tripid or same port OR tripid?

Comment: same port AND TripId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of grouping, a where condition and select the values you need:

```
YourList
.GroupBy(c => new { c.TripId, c.Port })
.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
.Select(grp => new { Port = grp.Key.Port, TripId = grp.Key.TripId });
```

Full working example:

```
public class Trip
{
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string TripId { get; set; }
    public string StatusId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Trip> tripList = new List<Trip>();

        tripList.Add(new Trip() { TripId = "123", Port = "1" });
        tripList.Add(new Trip() { TripId = "124", Port = "2" });
        tripList.Add(new Trip() { TripId = "124", Port = "3" });
        tripList.Add(new Trip() { TripId = "126", Port = "4" });
        tripList.Add(new Trip() { TripId = "126", Port = "4" });

        var doubleTrip = tripList
            .GroupBy(c => new { c.TripId, c.Port })
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
            .Select(grp => new { Port = grp.Key.Port, TripId = grp.Key.TripId });

        foreach (var d in doubleTrip)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TripId: {0}, Port: {1}", d.TripId, d.Port);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This is Excellent and was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Good :) added an example for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IEqualityComparer`.Your class implementation could look like this.

```
class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Trip> {

public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) {
    return x.Port == y.Port &&
        x.TripId== y.TripId;
}

public int GetHashCode(Trip obj) {
    return obj.Port.GetHashCode() ^
        obj.TripId.GetHashCode();
}
```

}

Then you can call to get distinct records-

```
var distinctRecords = YourList.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());
```